# React: Weird reconciliation result on list items whose content is served by array with same length as the list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, key, reusability

**UPDATE:** Problem is not solved but it turned out to be something else other than what it looked like when I first posted this. I modified the title to better describe what it is really about. Some comments in the code are updated to save some read time. **React does reuse element when it should**, result is weird when two arrays are of same length.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-reconciliation-0vlug) for quick check.

I came into this frustrating yet interesting issue, and have been struggled with it for quite a while, with no luck. Not sure if it is actually a bug of React.

According to the official documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html), if I'm understanding this right, by giving a correct key (unique within siblings) to an element, React should try to update and reuse it instead of destroying and recreating it on a re-render.

Check out this example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/mark-night/pen/bGpqvyL?editors=0010),  I've simplified it to just enough for showing the problem. Raw code is also included below for a quick reference.

The app is working fine if it is just as simple as is, so increase/decrease state `cur` (by clicking the two buttons) rolls numbers back and forth.

If you check it out in browser dev tools, to see what elements are destroyed and recreated on each button click, it's clear that every clicking on `+` destroys the first item and creates the last item, every clicking on `-` destroys the last item and create the first item, other `<li>`s in-between are just updated and reused. This is correct and expected.

**The problem:**

If `num` and `loop` happen to be of same length, e.g. change `num` to `[3, 4, 5, 6]` (remove any two items would be fine) so it has 4 items same as `loop` does, I'll expect to see all items being reused on button click and no item should be destroyed and recreated, as all items are in the same DOM tree with keys set to be easily identified.

However, if you check in browser dev tool again, it works quite differently indeed although nothing seems to be wrong on rendered result. Clicking on `+` destroys the first item and recreates it as the last item, while reusing all others. Clicking on `-` reuses first item (the last item from last render) and destroys/recreates all others.

Although the app still works without problem (because it's simple as just display some numbers), but all class driven transitions will mess up and all children elements under `<li>` reinitialize, e.g. `<img>` reload source images.

**Questions**

1. What's so special when two arrays are of same length in this case? What is really happening here?
2. What can or should be done to fix it? Meaning try to reuse existing items as much as possible. A quick dirty method I could think of is to insert some dummy item into `num` and add some logic in map() iteration to skip the dummy item. This works but I don't feel it as a 'correct' way.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]; // array to serve content to list items
const loop = [1, 2, 3, 4]; // array to be mapped to generate the list

const RollingNums = () => {
  const [cur, setCur] = React.useState(0); // control number rolling

  return (
    <div className="problem">
      <ul>
        {loop.map((value, index) => { // list items count is fixed
          // simple CS to get continued content from array num
          let idx = index + cur;
          idx =
            idx >= 0
              ? idx % num.length
              : ((idx % num.length) + num.length) % num.length;
          const target = num[idx].toString(); // content from array num for current element
          return (
            <li key={target} className={target}>
              {target}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
      <div className="control">
        <button onClick={() => setCur((prev) => prev - 1)}>-</button>
        <span>{cur}</span>
        <button onClick={() => setCur((prev) => prev + 1)}>+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<RollingNums />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

Comment: Your key is changing on every re-render. How do you expect to React to use the same last React element? Nevertheless, do [check this out](https://overreacted.io/react-as-a-ui-runtime/)

Comment: @PrãtéékThápá Thanks for the hint. Before I head over to the article you suggested, please allow me to comment a little bit: yes I assign keys on every render, but not new keys, instead, an existing key is picked and assigned. Indeed, as long as num has more items than loop does, everything work as expected. React DOES reuse/update the same element from last render, I've described this as clear as I could. This issue ONLY happens when num and loop are of same length.

Comment: As far as I can say, you're assigning new keys. For example, the first li has a different key with ever re-render with other li's as well. Not sure, I am understanding what you mean though.

Comment: I believe React works by keys rather than orders on reconciliation. Assigning keys on every render is natural way to direct React what to do on certain child element. Observe on cases where num has greater length than loop does perfectly reflect this, it’s just when two arrays have same length things start to be unexpected...

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be some issue with React, it does somehow remove and then recreate those items. Check [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19695), and particularly the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-reconciliation-result-on-list-elements-5gw67?file=/src/index.js) provided by Kunuk Nykjær.

In my work, I just took a quick dirty detour by extending the first array (`num`) to make sure it is longer than the second (`loop`), in which case React reconciliation does work as expected. This requires many extra check in my case, but that's all I could do for now.